# Node http.request does nothing

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

```
var http = require('http');

var options = {
    method: 'GET',
    host: 'www.google.com',
    port: 80,
    path: '/index.html'
};

http.request(
    options,
    function(err, resBody){
        console.log("hey");
        console.log(resBody);
        if (err) {
            console.log("YOYO");
            return;
        }
    }
);
```

For some reason this just times out and doesn't log anything to the console.

I'm aware that I could `require('request')` but I need to use `http` to be compatible with a plugin I'm using.

Also, background on my versions: Node is **v0.8.2**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the example here: http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback

```
var options = {
  hostname: 'www.google.com',
  port: 80,
  path: '/upload',
  method: 'POST'
};

var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
  console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
  console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
  res.setEncoding('utf8');
  res.on('data', function (chunk) {
    console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
  });
});

req.on('error', function(e) {
  console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
});

// write data to request body
req.write('data\n');
req.write('data\n');
req.end();
```

the callback does not have an error parameter, you should use on("error", ...)
and your request doesn't get sent till you call end()

Comment: `your request doesn't get sent till you call end()` Not true, it just doesn't _end_ the request until then. Try writing to the request, without ending and watching `ngrep`. The request is sent and data is written to the request over time, the TCP session just isn't closed until `.end()` is called. The reason his doesn't do anything is because nothing is written to the request, and it isn't ended so node is waiting to know what to send.

Comment: indeed, you are correct.  But the server will will wait to reply till you call end(), or it times out.

Comment: Depends on the response type, try doing a write with no end with his exact code and watch what happens on ngrep. Google responds immediately because that URL doesn't exist, and your app will get/parse the error response then exit. All without you ever calling end. I tried it out and watched it happen because I was skeptical of the assumption. I think it is due to 'GET" not having a body, so if you hit a write they figure you are done.

Comment: in fact, thinking about it some more, very interesting data point.  Thank you for doing the experiment!

Answer (score 3):

You prepared a request object, but didn't fire it with .end().  (Also the callback doesn't work that way.)

See: http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_event_request

Answer (score 0):

Couple things here:

- Use `hostname` not `host` so you are compatible with `url.parse()` ([see here](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback))
- The callback for request takes one argument which is an [`http.ClientResponse`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_clientresponse)
- To catch an error use `req.on('error', ...)`
- When using `http.request` you need to end the request when you are done `req.end()` this is so you can write any body you need to (with `req.write()`) before ending the request

  - Note: `http.get()` will do this for you under the hood, which may be why you forgot.

Working code:

```
var http = require('http');

var options = {
    method: 'GET',
    hostname: 'www.google.com',
    port: 80,
    path: '/index.html'
};

var req = http.request(
    options,
    function(res){
        console.log("hey");
        console.log(res);
    }
);

req.on('error', function(err) {
  console.log('problem', err);
});

req.end();
```